# Iterating through LevelDB or .DAT files to enumerate bitcoin addresses

Tags: blockchain, development

I'm looking for a library that can parse either the .DAT files or the .ldb files to enumerate bitcoin addresses.  Alternatively, if that can't be done via the standard .dat or .ldb, I'll take a different bitcoin server that can do so with its own database.

Comment: maybe: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/11687/reliable-efficient-way-to-parse-the-blockchain-into-a-sql-database